# Laravel JWT in Cookie Without Session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-5.6

I'm currently using Laravel 5.6 with the [Laravel JWT library](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) for a new web app.

I would like to store the JWT in a cookie without using a conventional session but there doesn't seem to be an easy way of going about this with the JWT library.

In my Auth controller I return the token in a cookie, but Laravel still starts a session which I don't want since I want the session inferred from the cookie.

I also went into Kernel.php and removed some of the Session stuff from the web middleware group but then that caused a runtime exception saying "Session store not set on request."

I've seen some hacked together solutions that were half implemented, but I would like hear some insight from anyone that has done this elegantly or felt like their solution was correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purpose I determined that using encrypted cookies will suffice for the web application (using Redis as a cache), and then using JWTs for the mobile API.